# Need help writing an array_diff() query for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP but that's not important. I have a variable that contains a standard array of positive int IDs. And I want to do a `SELECT` query with this array against a MySQL table to find out what IDs are not already existing in the data table. My first thought was to use `IN()` but then I realized that doing it that way I can only get a list of `IDs` that do exist not ones that don't. Of course with a list of IDs that do exist, I could compile it into a second array and then use `array_diff()` but I can't help wondering if there's another way to do it.

Comment: @PHPgrur select * from table while IDs NOT IN ('1','2'); have you tried this?

Comment: I think he wants to return all IDs in his list *minus* the ones that appear in the table.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I want a list of IDs from my array that do not exist in the database.

Comment: You can use `NOT IN` instead of `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use unset()

```
SELECT QUERY
where (row) {
   unset(id)
}
```